# Google play Services Plugin issue in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I just tried to create fire base login application in android

I am facing below issue, Can you know how to resolve this issue in AndroidStudio

**Error:(41, 0) Version: 4.2.42 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.**

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0' add it in gradle file

Comment: What version of Google Play Services do you use? Is it 4.2.42?

Comment: yes issue resolved